# (Andriod Studio) (Java) Having Trouble using the methods build in class B using ArrayList from Class A

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I have an Add Button that adds values to an `ArrayList`. I am having trouble passing the `ArrayList` in the `doMean` method to the `Calculator` class where the calculation methods are defined.

//Main class

```
ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();


public void doAdd(View v)
{
    EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
    String value = e.getText().toString();
    Double d = Double.parseDouble(value);

    numbers.add(d);

    e.setText("");
}

public void doMean(View v)
{
    double mean;

}
```

//Calculator Class

```java
public class Calculator{

    public ArrayList<Double> arr = new ArrayList<Double>();

    double m;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calculator STAT = new Calculator();
        STAT.stat();
    }

    public void stat()
    {
        m = getMean();
    }

    public double getMean()
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
        {
            sum = sum + arr.get(i);
        }
        double Mean = sum / arr.size();
        return Mean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the main method 
(`public static void main(String[] args)`) in an android project.
The way to run your code is to do it inside an activity.